# Are the sequential sum of squares appropriate when treatments must be applied in sequence?

Tags: anova, variance, sums-of-squares

I'm working with some modeled future stream flow data that was created in two steps.  First, future precipitation predictions (at certain points in a watershed) were created by running historical precipitation data through four precipitation models.  The output from those models (four runs per precipitation model) were then used as inputs in four different hydrologic models, which were used to generate future stream flow predictions (at those same points).  This was done in such a way that each combination of precipitation model and hyrdologic model were considered (i.e. crossed).

I'm trying to determine the relative importance of both precipitation model and hydrologic model choice on modeled stream flow, and have analyzed the output using a two factor linear model.  Unfortunately, due to some issues with two of the models, a number of data points had to be thrown out.  As a result, the model is unbalanced. So when looking at, say, the sum of squares, the type I and type II SS differ.  To note, both variables stay in the model during model selection.

I don't mean to resurrect a sum of squares debate.  But I'm curious, if in a situation like this, because the data was created by applying one treatment and then another, if it's more appropriate to apply sequential sum of squares than the type II sum of squares.

Many thanks!
Jon